# Flutter gesture on placing hand

Tags: flutter, gesture

Do we have a gesture in flutter that can detect if a hand has been placed on the screen. 
It shouldn't fire on tap with finger, but only when the hand is placed on the screen. I am trying to make a mockup of human palm scanning. Once the hand is placed on the screen, a scan action is mocked.

child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('Tapping'),
    child: Container( // child Container 
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text("A"),
    ),
  ),

I tried with gesture detector, taps work, but there is nothing to handle when the hand is placed on the screen.

However, in the background I can see following logs being fired when I place my hand on the screen.

```
 D/ViewRootImpl(17791): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:6.0
 D/ViewRootImpl(17791): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:3.0
 D/ViewRootImpl(17791): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:3.0
 D/ViewRootImpl(17791): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:3.0
 D/ViewRootImpl(17791): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:3.0
 D/ViewRootImpl(17791): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:3.0
```

This happens in the default flutter create project app also if we just keep the hand on the screen.
I feel my case will work if I can catch this trigger and handle it. Any ideas ?